# Concatenate two strings without intersection

Tags: java, string, string-concatenation

I need to concatenate two string in another one without their intersection (in terms of last/first words).

In example:

"Some little d" + "little dogs are so pretty" = "Some little dogs are so pretty"

"I love you" + "love" = "I love youlove"

What is the most efficient way to do this in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we go - if the first doesn't even contain the first letter of the second string, just return the concatenation. Otherwise, go from longest to shortest on the second string, seeing if the first ends with it. If so, return the non-overlapping parts, otherwise try one letter shorter.

```
 public static String docat(String f, String s) {
   if (!f.contains(s.substring(0,1)))
     return f + s;
   int idx = s.length();
   try {
     while (!f.endsWith(s.substring(0, idx--))) ;
   } catch (Exception e) { }
   return f + s.substring(idx + 1);
 }

 docat("Some little d", "little dogs are so pretty");
 -> "Some little dogs are so pretty"
 docat("Hello World", "World")
 -> "Hello World"
 docat("Hello", "World")
 -> "HelloWorld"
```

EDIT: In response to the comment, here is a method using arrays. I don't know how to stress test these properly, but none of them took over 1ms in my testing.

```
public static String docat2(String first, String second) {
  char[] f = first.toCharArray();
  char[] s = second.toCharArray();
  if (!first.contains("" + s[0]))
    return first + second;
  int idx = 0;
  try {
    while (!matches(f, s, idx)) idx++;
  } catch (Exception e) { }
  return first.substring(0, idx) + second;
}

private static boolean matches(char[] f, char[] s, int idx) {
  for (int i = idx; i <= f.length; i++) {
    if (f[i] != s[i - idx])
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: This is a good example but the OP wanted something more efficient. For a case with pretty little dogs this still creates a lot of temporary Strings. One can avoid this by first obtaining a `char[]` array of the Strings through `String.toCharArray()`, and implementing a custom `endsWith()` which compares two such arrays.

Comment: @user268396: Does the new version suit you more?

Comment: I think use this algorithm (char[] version). Seems simple and fast. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest: iterate over the first string taking suffixes ("Some little d", "ome little d", "me little d"...) and test the second string with `.startsWith`. When you find a match, concatenate the prefix of the first string with the second string.

Here's the code:

```
String overlappingConcat(String a, String b) {                              
  int i;
  int l = a.length();
  for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    if (b.startsWith(a.substring(i))) {
      return a.substring(0, i) + b;
    }
  }
  return a + b;
}
```

The biggest efficiency problem here is the creation of new strings at `substring`. Implementing a custom `stringMatchFrom(a, b, aOffset)` should improve it, and is trivial.

Comment: It is not very efficient, I was looking for something more powerful.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid creating unnecessary substrings with the regionMatches() method.

```
public static String intersecting_concatenate(String a, String b) {
    // Concatenate two strings, but if there is overlap at the intersection,
    // include the intersection/overlap only once.

    // find length of maximum possible match
    int len_a = a.length();
    int len_b = b.length();
    int max_match = (len_a > len_b) ? len_b : len_a;

    // search down from maximum match size, to get longest possible intersection
    for (int size=max_match; size>0; size--) {
        if (a.regionMatches(len_a - size, b, 0, size)) {
            return a + b.substring(size, len_b);
        }
    }

    // Didn't find any intersection. Fall back to straight concatenation.
    return a + b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code seems to work for the first example. I did not test it extensively, but you get the point. It basically searches for all occurrences of the first char of the `secondString` in the `firstString` since these are the only possible places where overlap can occur. Then it checks whether the rest of the first string is the start of the second string. Probably the code contains some errors when no overlap is found, ... but it was more an illustration of my answer

```
String firstString = "Some little d";
String secondString = "little dogs are so pretty";
String startChar = secondString.substring( 0, 1 );
int index = Math.max( 0, firstString.length() - secondString.length() );
int length = firstString.length();
int searchedIndex = -1;
while ( searchedIndex == -1 && ( index = firstString.indexOf( startChar, index ) )!= -1 ){
  if ( secondString.startsWith( firstString.substring( index, length ) ) ){
    searchedIndex = index;
  }
}
String result = firstString.substring( 0, searchedIndex ) + secondString;
```

Answer (score 0):

`isBlank(CharSequence)`, `join(T...)` and `left(String, int)` are methods from Apache Commons.

```
public static String joinOverlap(String s1, String s2) {
    if(isBlank(s1) || isBlank(s2)) { //empty or null input -> normal join
        return join(s1, s2);
    }

    int start = Math.max(0, s1.length() - s2.length());

    for(int i = start; i < s1.length(); i++) { //this loop is for start point
        for(int j = i; s1.charAt(j) == s2.charAt(j-i); j++) { //iterate until mismatch
            if(j == s1.length() - 1) { //was it s1's last char?
                return join(left(s1, i), s2);
            }
        }
    }

    return join(s1, s2); //no overlapping; do normal join
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a [suffix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree) of the first String, then traverse the tree from the root taking characters from the beginning of the second String and keeping track of the longest suffix found.

This should be the longest suffix of the first String that is a prefix of the second String. Remove the suffix, then append the second String.

This should all be possible in linear time instead of the quadratic time required to loop through and compare all suffixes.

Comment: If you have very large strings, creating a sophisticated mapping object could be a Big Win. But for modestly sized strings, the time and memory required to set up a suffix tree seems unlikely to pay dividends. For small N, a simple O(N**2) algorithm often beats a more complicated O(N). Real time takes large constants (setup time) into account, even if order statistics do not.

Comment: thank you for let me know what is a suffix tree, it's so much for this problem (the strings are many and short) but I think may be good for other problems.